# STL Unordered Map- inserting into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, insert, unordered-map

I am not too familiar with the STL's unordered map and I'm having trouble inserting elements into it.

So I have an unordered map where the key is a string and the mapped value is a vector of integers. I have it declared as:

```
              unordered_map<string, vector<int> > categorySearch;
```

How would I go about inserting elements into this map. I am currently doing

```
       categorySearch.insert(make_pair("hello", categorySearch["hello"].push_back(5)));
```

This is clearly giving me compiler errors. How do I use insert for the vector portion of the map.

Here is the compiler error I am getting:

```
logData.h: In member function ‘void LogData::addEntry(Log)’:
logData.h:23:68: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> >’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)
categorySearch.insert(make_pair(add.getCategory(), categorySearch[add.getCategory].push_back(data.size()-1)));
                                                                ^
logData.h:23:68: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/unordered_map:48:0,
             from logData.h:2,
             from logman.cpp:5:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h:595:7: note: std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::vector<int>; _Hash = std::hash<std::basic_string<char> >; _Pred = std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> > >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::vector<int>; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]
   operator[](const key_type& __k)
   ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h:595:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h:599:7: note: std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::vector<int>; _Hash = std::hash<std::basic_string<char> >; _Pred = std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> > >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::vector<int>; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]
   operator[](key_type&& __k)
   ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h:599:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> >::key_type&& {aka std::basic_string<char>&&}’
make: *** [logman.o] Error 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `second` in the pair is a `vector<int>`, so you construct a vector with 1 element initialized with 5 instead of `push_back`.

```
 categorySearch.insert(make_pair("hello", std::vector<int>(1,5)));
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/JlMUuN

If the item already exists, use the return value that `unordered_map::insert` gives you, which is a `std::pair` consisting of the iterator and a `bool` denoting the success of the insertion:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    typedef unordered_map<string, vector<int>> CMap;
    CMap category_map;
    category_map.insert(make_pair("hello", std::vector<int>(1, 5)));
    auto pr = category_map.insert(make_pair("hello", std::vector<int>(1, 5)));
    if (!pr.second)
        pr.first->second.push_back(10);
    cout << pr.first->second.size(); 
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/svEqcD

You will see that the map entry for "hello" has now 2 items in the vector, since the second call to `insert` failed due to item previously existing.

See here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert

Comment: Would this still work if I want to keep adding to that vector?

Comment: See my updated comments.  If the item already exists, the iterator that's returned is the one with the existing item, so I just pushed another value into it.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd take one of two approaches. The first possibility would be to use the map's `operator[]`, so the code looked like:

```
category_search["hello"].push_back(5);
```

The other obvious possibility would be to recognize that what you're creating (each key having multiple mapped values) is equivalent to what an `unordered_multimap` provides, so you could just use:

```
std::unordered_multimap<std::string, int> category_search;

category_search.emplace("hello", 5);
```

Note that I've also used `emplace` to simplify the code (and as a bonus, probably run a little faster as well).

And yes, both of these support multiple values, so you could add:

```
category_search["hello"].push_back(10);
```

... or:

```
category_search.emplace("hello", 10);
```

...to the `unordered_map`/`unordered_multimap` respectively to also associate the value `10` with the key `hello`.

In the case of the `unordered_multimap`, you'd retrieve the set of values associated with a particular key using `equal_range`, like:

```
auto p = category_search.equal_range("hello");
```

This will put the beginning of the range in `p.first` and the end in `p.second`.